# How to make only vertical scroll view?

Tags: iphone

I am trying make long screen to vertical direction.

So, I need a screen that has vertical scroll.

How to make it ?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the UIScrollView has `contentSize.width ≤ bounds.width` there won't be horizontal scroll.